# Where is definition of "write" function in FreeBSD OS

Tags: freebsd

Hey I want to know how the "write" function is implemented in FreeBSD10 OS.
I cannot find anywhere in the OS code.

Basically my thread is getting blocked in the "write" system call. Some one let me know where I can find the definition of write function.

Comment: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/sys/write.c

Answer (score 1):

`man 2 write` on your system or https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?write(2)

FreeBSD's documentation is excellent and you can find such things easily just using the man pages.